# How to get all unique HTML tags on a webpage using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I have html source code from an HTML page:

```
import requests

text = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture").text
```

What I would like to do is to get a count of the number of unique HTML tags on this page.

For example: `<head>`, `<title>`. Closing tags do not count (`<head>` and `</head>` would be counted only once).

Yes, I know this is much easier using HTML parsers such as Beautiful Soup but I would like to accomplish this using only Regular Expression.

I've brute force counted this and the answer is in the ballpark of around 60 unique tags.
How would I go about doing this?

I've already tried using `re.findall()`, to no avail.

Since the answer is around 60, I would like the output to be:

```
"Number of unique HTML tags: 60"
```

Comment: did you get exactly 60 unique tags? I get around 42?

Comment: yes, I got 42 before as well, but I do not think that this includes the self-closing tags, such as "<meta charset="UTF-8"/>". I cannot figure out a way to add the self-closing tags to the 42, which comes out to be about 60. @akin_ai

Answer (score 0):

The following will yield 63 URL's from the url in question

```
import requests
import re

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture"
text = requests.get(url).text

url_pattern = r"((http(s)?://)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+[.com]+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)"

# Get all matching patterns of url_pattern
# this will return a list of tuples 
# where we are only interested in the first item of the tuple
urls = re.findall(url_pattern, text)

# using list comprehension to get the first item of the tuple, 
# and the set function to filter out duplicates
unique_urls = set([x[0] for x in urls])
print(f'Number of unique HTML tags: {len(unique_urls)} found on {url}')
```

out:

```
Number of unique HTML tags: 63 found on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture
```

Answer (score 0):

Please! Do not parse a HTML in regex use modules like bs4. But still if you insist Do that as follows:

```
import requests
import re

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture'
text = requests.get(url).text
tags = re.findall('<[^>]*>',text)

total=[]

for i in range(len(tags)):
    total.append(re.match('<[^\s\>]+',tags[i]).group())

total=[elem+'>' for elem in total]
r= re.compile('</[^<]')

unwanted =list(filter(r.match,total))

un=['<!-->','<!--[if>','<!DOCTYPE>','<![endif]-->']
unwanted.extend(un)

final=[x for x in list(set(total)) if x not in set(unwanted)]

print('Number of Unique HTML tags : ',len(final))
```

Comment: I'm new to regex and I've manually added a unwanted list . But hey it works and print the number of unique tags to be 62. Hope it helps @justanothercoder